# How to create festival calendar in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005

I want to make a festival calendar using asp.net from that I used two ajax calendar and one textbox it is a festival textbox where we enter festival which FromDate and ToDate respectively. I want to do this as following point

1. If I enter in textbox Christmas and Choose Fromdate=25/12/2011 and ToDate=31/12/2011 then it will be valid
2. If I choose fromDate=25/12/2011 and ToDate=24/12/2011 then it will invalid
3. If I choose Fromdate=25/12/2011 and Todate=28/12/2011 then also it is invalid because it coming in between 25/12/2011 and 31/12/2011
4. If I Choose fromdate=1/1/2011 and ToDate=1/1/2011 then it is valid
5. If I choose fromdate=21/12/2011 and 25/12/2011 then it is invalid because of already Christmas done in 1/1/2011

And all date should show in gridview like 25-dec-2011 format

Here is my code:

```
DateTime dt1 = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_fromdate.Text);
DateTime dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(txt_todate.Text);
if (dt1 > dt2)
{
    con.Open();
    com = new SqlCommand("BTNN_MovieDB_Festival_Details_Insert", con);
    com.Parameters.Add("@fromdate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateformat_mmdd(txt_fromdate.Text.ToString().Trim());
    com.Parameters.Add("@todate", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = dateformat_mmdd(txt_todate.Text.ToString().Trim());
    com.Parameters.Add("@return", SqlDbType.VarChar).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    showdata();
}
else if (dt1 < dt2)
{
    lblerror.Text = "ToDate should be greater than FromDate";

}
```

Comment: It useful if you can show or talk through what you have tried already along these lines. Which part are you stuck on? Use of text boxes? Validation? Gridview? Currently it sound like you are just asking for the whole program so you'll have to narrow it down a bit...

Comment: i have problem in point 3,4 and 5

Comment: Is this the same question as the [one you posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405205/how-to-to-make-festival-calender-in-asp-net) about 13 hours ago?

Comment: You have not provided enough information on valid and invalid cases. Can you point out what code you have and if possible put it in your post

Comment: yes sir i know but no one giving me reply that's why :(

Comment: I don't understand why case 3 & 5 are invalid.

Comment: @Atul: Could you give us more exact specifications of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: because it already enter like fromdate=25/12/2011 and todate=31/12/2011 point 3 is suggest that there should be no date in between

Comment: "yes sir i know but no one giving me reply that's why :(" - that is not a reason to keep asking the same question. Please refrain from doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should function

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // allFestivals holds all the festival list 
        // allFestivals values may come from some other data source like database
        List<Festival> allFestivals =new List<Festival>();

        // Simulate by inserting Christmas 
        Festival chirstmas = new Festival() 
        { 
            Name = "Christmas", 
            startDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 25), 
            endDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 31) 
        };
        AddFestival(allFestivals, chirstmas);

        // NewYear will not be inserted since 31-12-2011 is already 
        // marked as holiday by Christmas
        AddFestival(allFestivals, new Festival()
        {
            Name = "NewYear",
            startDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 31),
            endDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 01)
        });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add new festival to the list of festivals
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="allFestivals"></param>
    /// <param name="newFestival"></param>
    static void AddFestival(List<Festival> allFestivals, Festival newFestival)
    {
        // If newFestival meets all the criteria only then add to the list
        if (ValidDates(newFestival) &&
            !NameExists(allFestivals, newFestival) &&
            !NonHoliday(allFestivals, newFestival) )
        {
            // allFestivals values may be strored into database
            allFestivals.Add(newFestival);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the newFestival startDate or endDate falls within any of the already
    /// existing festival start and end date
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dates"></param>
    /// <param name="newFestival"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool NonHoliday(List<Festival> dates, Festival newFestival)
    {
        return dates.Exists((date) => 
            newFestival.startDate >= date.startDate && newFestival.startDate <= date.endDate ||
            newFestival.endDate >= date.startDate && newFestival.endDate <= date.endDate);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// If the festival name already exists, returns true else false
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dates"></param>
    /// <param name="newFestival"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool NameExists(List<Festival> dates, Festival newFestival)
    {
        return dates != null && 
            dates.Count() > 0  && 
            dates.FirstOrDefault((dt) => dt.Name == newFestival.Name) != null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Validate if end date is greater than or equal to start date
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newFestival"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static bool ValidDates(Festival newFestival)
    {
        return newFestival.endDate >= newFestival.startDate;
    }

    // Data structure represenging festival details
    class Festival
    {
        public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: thanx sandeep ur reply but my requirement little different my edit my whole problem...

Comment: sandeep user can enter any festival and if you don't mind can you explain your code im didn't get

Comment: @Atul, I have provided enough comments for your understanding

Comment: ok sandeep thanx a lot your help but having little doubt  Festival chirstmas = new Festival() 
        { 
            Name = "Christmas", 
            startDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 25), 
            endDate = new DateTime(2011, 12, 31) 
        };
means in my side user will be choose date ajax calender he will not write manually and second part is Christmas is festival is user should write in textbox ...

Comment: that's right. wherever there is FestivalDate creation, you can replace that with your custom code.

Comment: that means every time i want to change festival n festival dates ??

Comment: @Atul, what I have provided is the business logic and skeleton for the solution. You need to judiciously include your specific logic for input and output like getting data from UI and updating to database.

Comment: U have to just enter dates ...  and validation , festival calender generation will be possible through stored proc. also

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the full syntax, but should help you see what you need to do:

```
DateTime d1 = txtDate1.Text;
DateTime d2 = txtDate2.Text;

if (d1 < d2){
   //Invalid
}

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE ([FromDate]<@Date1 AND [ToDate]>@Date1) OR (([FromDate]<@Date2 AND [ToDate]>@Date2)", conn);

//TODO: Add Parameters

if (((int)cmd.executescalar())>0){
    //Invalid
}
```

Comment: I assume this should take into account the situation where from is 23/12 and to is 1/1 (ie an existing internval is entirely inside the new one). It wasn't explicitly asked for but I'm pretty sure that is just a case that was missed out... :)

Comment: friends Point 3,4 and 5 is looking tough, im not getting how will i show invalid invalid date if it is coming given date i know that we are using between query but how will? 4 point it little easy so it's ok but in point 5 im not getting ...

Comment: hey friends someone please help me  :(

Comment: hey someone help me out this problem pls